# How to use multidimensional arrays in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

How can I use a bidimensional array in gnuplot? I could not find anything like that on the internet, nor on the user manual.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very dirty workaround, though I do hope there is something better out there.

In gnuplot's new versions (at least from version 4.6, though maybe this works in older versions too) you can define case functions via the ternary operator. Use this to define a function that behaves like an array.

Suppose your array is simply

```
A = 1 2
    3 4
```

Then you can define

```
A(i,j) = ( i == 1 ? A1(j) : i == 2 ? A2(j) : 'error')
A1(j)  = ( j == 1 ? 1 : j == 2 ? 2 : 'error')
A2(j)  = ( j == 1 ? 3 : j == 2 ? 4 : 'error')
```

This can also be used to define associative arrays (e.g. `i` and `j` can also be characters), however changing this 'array' at runtime would be very cumbersome, since you would have to redefine the whole line function every time you want to change an entry.

That is, if the array changes at runtime then you might find it best to declare

```
A11 = 1; A12 = 2; A21 = 3; A22 = 4
A1(j)  = ( j == 1 ? A11 : j == 2 ? A12 : 'error')
A2(j)  = ( j == 1 ? A21 : j == 2 ? A22 : 'error')
```

and redefine the variables `Aij` as needed.

Comment: Do you have an example for what you need an array in gnuplot? Maybe there is another way to solve your problem.